# InvalidRegistration respond from FCM

Tags: ios, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes)

> Check the format of the registration token you pass to the server. Make sure it matches the registration token the client app receives from registering with Firebase Notifications. Do not truncate or add additional characters.

So I checked FCM token that iOS app receives with the token that database stores. They are [identical](https://www.diffchecker.com/uAfunuWY)
[image]

Nevertheless, I keep receiving the same error over and over again

```
"result":{
     "multicast_id":8326997376324259978,
     "success":0,
     "failure":1,
     "canonical_ids":0,
     "results":[{
            "error":"InvalidRegistration"
      }
]}
```

Can somebody open my eyes to what is missed?

....pleeeeease

Comment: No answers so far....what peace of the information you need to shed light?

Answer (score 0):

While fcm request preparation

```
private function sendPushNotificationToIOS($tokens, $notification) {
     $fields = array(
        'registration_ids'  => $tokens,
        'priority'          => 'high',
        'content_available' => true,
        'mutable_content'   => true,
        'notification'      => $notification,
        'data'              => $notification,
     );
}
```

I sent `$tokens` as Laravel collection, that is why I didn't get any error from my server.
So make sure you use Array.